# How can I hide the sidebar on specific pages?

Tags: sidebar, theme-twenty-ten

I'm using a child of the `twentyten` default theme and I want to hide the sidebar on some pages.

What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, Twentyten has a no-sidebar page template already.

[image: before]

Modify the template option in the page edit screen:

[image: Template Option]

And viola:

[image: After]

Comment: John, how can I increase the page width *only for this specific page*?

Answer (score 1):

create a new page template, simply duplicate the current page.php or index.php. remove the following:

```
<?php get_sidebar();?>
```

and place a template title at the top of the file

```
<?php
/*
Template: No-Sidebar Template
*/
?>
```

Then you can choose that when publishing.

NOTE: This will probably impact on your styles, may need to tweak your stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) on your standard page file template

```
if( ! is_page('page_name')){ get_sidebar();}
```

or

```
if( ! is_page(page_id) ){ get_sidebar();}
```

You can also pass an array

```
is_page(array(42,'about-me','About Me And Joe'))
```